# How to get all classes that implement same interface?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, solid-principles

I have a design issue. I want to have separate class for every validation. Also, I want to have one class that call all this validations. Idea is that if I need new validation, then I just add new validation class and everything works. I don't need to change anything else, just add new class.
Something like this:

```
    public interface IValidate{
        bool Validate();
    }

    public class Validator1 : IValidate{    
        public bool Validate(){     
            //Do validation 1
        }
    }
    public class Validator2 : IValidate{    
        public bool Validate(){     
            //Do validation 2
        }
    }
    //...
    public class ValidatorN : IValidate{    
        public bool Validate(){     
            //Do validation N
        }
    }
    //...................................
    public interface IValAll{
        bool Validate_All();
    }
    public class ValidateAll : IValAll{
        public bool Validate_All(){     
             //Call all validators that implements IValidate interface
            //Do validation 1,2...N
            //If all validations return true, than this function return true. 
            //Else return false.
        }
    }
```

I don't know if this is best approach, but you get an idea what I want. Problem is that I don't know how to implement this Validate_All() method.

*How to get all classes that implement same interface and do validation in one loop?*

Idea is to inject this IValAll interface and do all validation with one call. 
Also, if you think that my design is not good, please feel free to tell me. I can change approach if someone have better idea.

Comment: `listofAll.OfType<IValidate>()` ???

Comment: Since none of these items are `static`, you require a reference to a list of objects with which to validate. You cannot get **all** the objects in your program of that type, you have to pass them in. Unless you mark the classes `static` and then commence the validation merely on their type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can inject all classes implementing `IValidate` via [*constructor injection*](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/177649/what-is-constructor-injection) into the class responsible for validating them all:

```
public class UltimateValidator
{
    private IValidate[] validators

    public UltimateValidator(IValidate[] validators)
    {
         this.validators = validators;
    }

    public bool ValidateAll()
    {
          foreach (var validator in validators)
          {
                 if (validator.Validate())
                 {
                      // etc.
                 }
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this. Can you please show me how to register ' IValidate[] ' array.With Unity or Autofac.

Comment: @user It's not complicated at all. Start [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660923%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx#registertype_mapping)